# Scrapy returning empty array from XPath

Tags: python, python-3.x, xpath, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm trying to collect data on an athlete from this webpage: https://www.athletic.net/TrackAndField/Athlete.aspx?AID=7844096#!/L4. I've been able to collect the athlete's name, but am having difficulty collecting their school name using the same method. I know the school name is contained as text within a link inside the  block, but it only returns an empty array.

Here is my code:

```
import scrapy

class AthletesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'athletes'
    allowed_domains = ['athletic.net']
    start_urls = ['https://www.athletic.net/TrackAndField/Athlete.aspx?AID=7844096#!/L0']

    def parse(self, response):
        yield {
            'athlete_name' : response.xpath("//h2/text()").extract_first(),
            'school_name' : response.xpath("//h1/a/text()").extract_first()
        }
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

Add a comma in your dictionary

```
import scrapy

class AthletesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'athletes'
    allowed_domains = ['athletic.net']
    start_urls = ['https://www.athletic.net/TrackAndField/Athlete.aspx?AID=7844096#!/L0']

    def parse(self, response):
        yield {
            'athlete_name' : response.xpath("//h2/text()").extract_first(), <--here
            'school_name' : response.xpath("//h1/a/text()").extract_first()
        }
```

Comment: Oh my god, thank you that was stupid. But the second line still returns an empty array instead of the school name - is there something else missing?

Comment: One thing you could try is (if you have chrome) to inspect the page, find the element, right click, and click copy xpath. That's usually what I do to identify elements easily.

Comment: I got: `//*[@id="anetMain"]/div[3]/team-nav/div/div/team-nav-logo/div/div/h1/a` for the school element.

Comment: Oh, that's a helpful tip! But I'm getting another "invalid syntax" error when I tried running `'school_name' : response.xpath("//*[@id="anetMain"]/div[3]/team-nav/div/div/team-nav-logo/div/div/h1/a").extract_first()`

Comment: That's cause you need to put it in single quotes, not double quotes :)

Comment: `'school_name' : response.xpath('//*[@id="anetMain"]/div[3]/team-nav/div/div/team-nav-logo/div/div/h1/a').extract_first()`

Comment: Sorry if these are stupid questions, I'm very new here - but replacing that line still returns an empty array.

Comment: Add a `/text()` to the xpath

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173845/discussion-between-kreesh-and-3000).